# Randomly generating a tibble with probability ifelse conditions based on another column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simulation by randomly generating a tibble with conditions based on probabilities.

This is what I've tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
N <- 500000
p_s <- 0.008
population <- tibble(status = sample(c("A", "T"), 
                                 N, 
                                 replace = TRUE, 
                                 prob = c(p_s, 1 - p_s)),
                 trait = sample(c("P", "N"), N, 
                                replace = TRUE, 
                                prob = c(
                                  (ifelse(status == "A", 0.3, 0.005)), 
                                  (ifelse(status == "A", 1-0.3, 1-0.005)))))
```

I want my tibble to have two columns:

one column will be "status," which can either be A (with a probability of 0.008) and T (with a probability of 1-0.008).

The other column will be "trait."

I want the trait to have a 0.3 probability of being "P" when the status is "A" or a 1-0.3 probability of being "N" when the status is "T."

I also want the trait to have a 0.005 probability of being "P" if the status is "A" or a 1-0.005 probability of being "N" when the status is "T."

My code returns this error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : incorrect number of probabilities

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In `ifelse` all the arguments should have same length.  By doing `c(` you are violating that

Comment: how do I have separate conditional statements for my second binary status variable without c( ?

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the `c()` in the `prob` with all the elements which violate the rule of having equal `length` for all arguments in `ifelse`, we can create the 'p1', 'p2' columns separately, then do a `group_by` the 'status' and use the `first` value of 'p1', and 'p2' in `sample`

```
library(dplyr)
N <- 50
out <- tibble(status = sample(c("A", "T"), 
                             N, 
                             replace = TRUE, 
                             prob = c(p_s, 1 - p_s))) %>%
   mutate(p1 = ifelse(status == 'A', 0.3, 0.005),
          p2 = 1- p1) %>% 
  group_by(status) %>%
  transmute(status, trait = sample(c("P", "N"), n(), 
        replace = TRUE, prob = c(first(p1), first(p2)))) %>%
  ungroup

head(out)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  status trait
#  <chr>  <chr>
#1 T      N    
#2 T      N    
#3 T      N    
#4 T      N    
#5 T      N    
#6 T      N
```